# How to keep a node at the centre of circle layout in cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am trying to show metabolite-protein interaction using cytoscape.min.js. I am using the circle layout to view the network.

I have two types of node in the network,"prot" and "met". For the better visualization, I want to create a circular layout with the node "met" at the center. In this case, I want to keep the metabolite (here node 'a') at the center of the circle. How to do the same ?

Thanks,

Santosh

My script for cytoscape.min.js is as follows:

```
<script>
      var cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cy'),
elements: [
  // nodes
  { data: { id: 'a', type: "met" } },
  { data: { id: 'b', type: "prot" } },
  { data: { id: 'c', type: "prot" } },
  { data: { id: 'd', type: "prot" } },
  { data: { id: 'e', type: "prot" } },
  { data: { id: 'f', type: "prot" } },
  // edges
  {
    data: {
      id: 'ab',
      source: 'a',
      target: 'b'
    }
  },
  {
     data: {
      id: 'ae',
      source: 'a',
      target: 'e'
    }
  }, 
  {
    data: {
      id: 'cd',
      source: 'c',
      target: 'd'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'ef',
      source: 'e',
      target: 'f'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'ac',
      source: 'a',
      target: 'c'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'be',
      source: 'b',
      target: 'e'
    }
  }
], 
        style: [
  {
    selector: 'node[type="prot"]',
    style: {
      'shape': 'circle',
      'background-color': 'red',
      label: 'data(id)'
    }
  },
  {
    selector: 'node[type="met"]',
    style: {
      'shape': 'square',
      'background-color': 'blue',
      label: 'data(id)'
    }
  }]
      });
      cy.layout({
    name: 'circle',
    animate: true
}).run();
</script>
```

Comment: You should use the concentric layout for this purpose.